# In Laravel Backpack - How to align a column to the right using addColumn

Tags: laravel-backpack

There is number column which represents price. How to align it to the right in the table grid.
I tired

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
            'name' => 'amount',
            'type' => 'number',
            'label' => 'Amount',
            'align' => 'right',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... I don't think there's a way to do that with existing columns. But a fast way to achieve it would be to [create your own column type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#section-roll-your-own), say... `number_aligned_right`, based on [the code for the numbers column](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/columns/number.blade.php).

Answer (score 4):

There wasn't a way in 2018, but in 2021 I can align a column to the right by using a wrapper like this:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
    'name' => 'amount',
    'type' => 'number',
    'label' => 'Amount',
    'wrapper' => [
        'element' => 'span',
        'style' => 'float:right',
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

found a better solution with the bootstrap class. main idea from => @paulh

```
'wrapper' => [
                'element' => 'div',
                'class' => 'text-right',
            ],
```